# JMETER Error - Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, solace

I am trying to run JMeter on linux machine to test Solace. i am using jndi.properties and using JMS publisher and subscriber samplers. i have added jndi.properties in user.classpath and even created a jar file of jndi.properties and added to class path.even then i receive below error while executing the test on linux. same script and method works on windows though.

Need to specify class name in environment or system property, or as an applet parameter, or in an application resource file:  java.naming.factory.initial
at javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getInitialContext(NamingManager.java:662) ~[?:1.8.0_281]

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMS Publisher documentation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JMS_Publisher):

> use jndi.properties. Note that the file **must be on the classpath** - e.g. by updating the user.classpath JMeter property. If this option is not selected, JMeter uses the "JNDI Initial Context Factory" and "Provider URL" fields to create the connection.

- The root of JMeter's classpath is it's "bin" folder
- Alternatively you can add this file to any .jar under JMeter's "lib" folder
- Third option is to copy it to JAVA_HOME/lib/ folder
- And last but not the least you can specify these properties in *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation) and untick "Use jndi.properties" file in the JMS Publisher GUI

More information:

- [Specifying Environment Properties](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/env/source.html)
- [JMeter Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)

Comment: Thanks @Dimitri T, i have updated system.properties and its working like a charm.